# how to find index of tuple?

Tags: ios, swift

i have myrecord class ..i need to find the index of object from tuple array

```
var transactionsGroupedByDate = [(String,Array<MyCushyRecords>)]()
```

where my object is myrecord object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var transactionsGroupedByDate = [(String,Array<MyCushyRecords>)]()
```

i just changed Array of MyCushyRecords class  to [Int] to finding index of tuples cause i don't know what exact your model does something like below

```
var transactionsGroupedByDate = [(String,[Int])]()
```

Now you can get index value like below,

```
var index:Int? = nil

for i in 0..<transactionsGroupedByDate.count {
    let result = zip(transactionsGroupedByDate[i].1, YOUR_VALUE).enumerated().filter() {
        $1.0 == $1.1
        }.map{$0.0}
  // result gives matches index value from both Int arrays.
    if result.count == YOUR_VALUE.count {
        index = i
        break
    }
}

//here you can check index of specific value in tuples 

if index != nil {
    print(index ?? "failed")
}else {
    print("No matched values")
}
```

Comment: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'Array< myRecord >' operands